# If $\vec x \times \vec y = \vec x \times \vec z = \vec z \times \vec y \neq0 $ then $\vec z = $?

Tags: geometry, cross-product

If$$\vec x \times \vec y = \vec x \times \vec z  = \vec z \times \vec y \neq0 ,$$ then it must be: $$\vec z = 1\vec x + 1\vec y+0\vec x \times \vec y\ ? $$
How can I come to this conclusion?

Comment: You can't. Actually, the $0$ can be replaced by anything.

Comment: @QuangHoang Adding $\vec{x}\times \vec{y}$ to $\vec{z}$ would violate the equations above. For instance, $(\hat{x}\times \hat{y})\times \hat{y}=\hat{z}\times \hat{y}=-\hat{x}\neq 0$.

Comment: @Semiclassical  you are right. Somehow I though $(x\times y)\times y=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $x\times y=x\times z$ and $x\ne0$ we can conclude that $z-y=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$, or $z=y+\lambda x$. Plugging this into the equation $x\times z=z\times y$ gives
$$x\times(y+\lambda x)=(y+\lambda x)\times y\ ,$$
which allows to conclude that $\lambda=1$, since $x\times y\ne0$. It follows that necessarily $z=x+y$. On the other hand it is easily verfied that this $z$ satisfies all requirements.